# Select all rows with top N most frequent columns for each Group

Tags: mysql, sql

For each Group, I want to get the rows with most popular columns.

Here is an example,
I have table with country, state and names.

For each country, I will select the rows with top 2 most popular names.
For USA, The 2 most popular names are John and Joe; For Canada they are Will and Rafe.

[image]

Here is the input table in text format.

| Country | State | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | CA | John |
| USA | WA | Jack |
| USA | CA | Joe |
| USA | CT | Joe |
| USA | MN | John |
| Canada | AB | Joe |
| Canada | AB | Rafe |
| Canada | AB | Will |
| Canada | BC | Will |
| Canada | BC | Rafe |

Also, the output table.

| Country | State | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | CA | John |
| USA | CA | Joe |
| USA | CT | Joe |
| USA | MN | John |
| Canada | AB | Rafe |
| Canada | AB | Will |
| Canada | BC | Will |
| Canada | BC | Rafe |

Comment: As described in the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), help us help you and edit your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample data and desired results as *consumable text*, not [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Stu . I added the tables in text format.

Comment: you need a unique column that desbies the order of the states, so that we can nknow why you choose ca and not mn

Comment: State column here has nothing to do with the rows being selected. You can assume there is another column named, row_id with unique values. But that would not change how these rows are being selected. Selection is based on frequency of the "Name" column for each Country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your mysql version supports the window function, we can use `COUNT` aggregate to get counting each by grouping `Name` and `Country`.

Then use self-join with `ROW_NUMBER` to find most top 2 popular names in each country's name.

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM (
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY cnt desc) rn 
  FROM (
    SELECT Name,Country,COUNT(*)  cnt
    FROM T
    GROUP BY Name,Country
  ) t1
) t1
INNER JOIN T t2
ON t1.Country = t2.Country AND t1.Name = t2.Name
WHERE rn <= 2
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=267da8ffd538a949474eb9f4f57b39c6)